# How to remove kapoor smell from clothes? Is smelling kapoor is dangerous?

Tags: clothing, smell

During the summers when we do not need warm woolens, or during the winters when we do not need light cotton clothes, we have to store them away till we can use them later. We put kapoor pill in it but when we get out these to use them again in the season they give a pungent smell. How to remove it from clothes? Is it harmful for newborn babies?

Comment: What is kapoor?

Comment: I think it is known as camphor in other countries.

Answer (score 1):

The smell should go away easily after one wash and drying in the sun. Camphor is not harmful, neither for babies nor for adults. It proves to be a good remedy for blocked nose is winter season.
Naphthalene balls are used to store clothes for a long time by most of the people in the world so you should also use them instead of using camphor.